# OpenJPA OneToMany and composite key in parent and child table

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I have tables with composited primary key.

```
Server(key=ServerId)
ServerId|Name
1       |server1
2       |server2
ParentObj(key=ServerId+Code)
ServerId|Code |Title
1       |code1|value1
1       |code2|value2
2       |code1|Value2b
ChildObj(key=ServerId+Code+Name)
ServerId|Code |Name |Value
1       |code1|prop1|val1
1       |code1|prop2|val2
1       |code2|prop1|val1b
2       |code1|prop3|val3
```

This is Java beans I have.

```
@Entity @Table(name="ParentObj") @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@IdClass(value=ParentObj.PK.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlRootElement
public class ParentObj {
   @Id private long serverId;
   @Id private String code;
   private String title;

   public long getServerId() { return serverId; }
   public String getCode() { return code; }
   public String getTitle() { return title; }

   public static class PK implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;       
     private long serverId;
     private String code;

     public long getServerId() { return serverId; }
     public void setServerId(long id) { serverId=id; }
     public String getCode() { return code; }
     public void setCode(String code) { this.code=code; }
  }
}

@Entity @Table(name="ChildObj") @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@IdClass(value=ChildObj.PK.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlRootElement
public class ChildObj {
   @Id private long serverId;
   @Id private String code;
   @Id private String name;
   private String value;
   // public getter+setters for each field

   public static class PK implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;       
     private long serverId;
     private String code;
     private String name;

     public long getServerId() { return serverId; }
     public void setServerId(long id) { serverId=id; }
     public String getCode() { return code; }
     public void setCode(String code) { this.code=code; }
     public String getName() { return name; }
     public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; }
  }
}
```

I have been trying "everything" to create OneToMany mapping(ParentObj->ChildObj) but nothing seem to work. I don't need ManyToOne(ParentObj<-ChildObj) link but that's ok if one must be defined.

This is a legacy database so I cannot insert an auto_increment identity column or create extra join table between parent and childs.

This annotation is conceptually what I want but multiple join columns is not accepted by OpenJPA2.x library.

```
// from parent to zero or more childs
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="server_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code")
})
private List<ChildObj> properties;
```

**Edit, answer**
OneToMany, ManyToOne and EmbeddedId annotations works. I have only tried reading existing rows but its fine for now. Later I try update+insert+delete tasks.

```
public class ParentObj {
   @EmbeddedId ParentObj.PK pk;
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true)
   private List<ChildObj> childs;

   public PK getPK() { return pk; }
   public void setPK(PK pk) { this.pk=pk; }
   public List<ChildObj> getChilds() { return childs; }
   ...

   @Embeddable @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
   public static class PK implements Serializable {    
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;     
       @Column(nullable=false) private long serverId;
       @Column(nullable=false) private String code;
       ..getters+setters+hashCode+equals functions
   }
}

public class ChildObj {
   @EmbeddedId ChildObj.PK pk;
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, optional=false)
      @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="serverid", referencedColumnName="serverid", nullable=false), 
      @JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code", nullable=false)
   })   
   private ParentObj parent;

   public PK getPK() { return pk; }
   public void setPK(PK pk) { this.pk=pk; }
   public long getServerId() { return pk.getServerId(); }
   public String getCode() { return pk.getCode(); }
   public String getName() { return pk.getName(); }
   ...

   @Embeddable @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
   public static class PK implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;      
      @Column(nullable=false) private long serverId;
      @Column(nullable=false) private String code;
      @Column(nullable=false) private String name;
      ..getters+setters+hashCode+equals functions
   }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create a `@ManyToOne` association from `ChildObj` to `ParentObj`, and then use `mappedBy` for the `@oneToMany` in `ParentObj`. Also, I would recommend you use an `@EmbeddedId` with an `@Embeddable` PK class.

Comment: It works and EmbeddedId did less duplicate code. thx. If you post an answer I can accept it properly.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but note that your `@Embeddable` class should be a separate (not inner) class - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an association from `ChildObj` to `ParentObj` similar to the following:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "serverId", referencedColumnName = "serverId"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "code")})
private ParentObj parentObj;
```

and then define the `@OneToMany` association in `ParentObj` like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentObj", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ChildObj> children;
```

I would also recommend that you define your composite keys as `@Embeddable` classes, used as `@EmbeddedId` references in the Entities. These embeddable PK classes should be separate classes (not inner classes), as you will use them separately to query the related Entities, and [serialisation of inner classes can cause problems](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/SER05-J.+Do+not+serialize+instances+of+inner+classes)

Comment: I use *public static class PK {...}* inner class(static) and retrieval seems to work fine, for time being I keep it this way before doing final implementation.